# random response from facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is weird.
I am developing a site that has differents articles and I want to implement an og.like button.
So I'm using javascript graph api.

When user clicks on my personalized like button the script does following to see if user already likes the article:

```
FB.api( "/", "POST", {
    batch: [
      { method :"GET",  name :"object_id",  relative_url :"/?id=<?php echo $canonical_url; ?>&fields=og_object"},
      { method :"GET",  relative_url :"?id={result=object_id:$.og_object.id}&fields=reactions.limit(0).summary(true)"}
    ]
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
          result = JSON.parse(response[1]['body']);
          console.log(result.reactions.summary.viewer_reaction);
      }
      else {
          console.log(response);
      }
    }
);
```

and the answer is:

SOMETIMES **LIKE**

SOMETIMES **NONE**

it seems to be completely random, any suggestion?

Comment: For the same user, or for different ones?

Comment: the same user, I'm just clicking the same button many times in the same page without reloading and I get allways different response

Comment: _“I'm just clicking the same button many times in the same page”_ - that’s not a normal use case ... does the problem actually exist when you browse the pages _normally_?

Comment: "normal use case"... mmm... I think getting a random response isn't normal... the use I make of it is indistinct.

Comment: No, hammering the API with requests is not normal. I hope you are not planing on doing this on every page load? That would likely make you run into the [rate limits](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) quite quickly. You should really do this on the server side, and cache the results.

Comment: anyway, it does not matter. I'm not hammering the API and the normal use is not to execute that function many times, just once... but the answer is not always the same, which has nosense

Comment: Well if you can reproduce the issue reliably, file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/